# raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511414] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, serial, usb-hub

Setup = Rpi > USB HUB > USB TTL adapter/cable > 2 LTE modules.

Protocol = AT Commands.

Problem =  mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

Question = Any investigation method and solution?

[image]

Error Log

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511414] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511441] [1057d8fd] FCM< b849a0d0 b849a148

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511456] [1057d900] RSP  900 0

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511470] [1057d902] FCM> b849a0d0 0

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511484] [1057d903] CMD  19 200

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511499] [1057d904] REQ> b849a0d0 0

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511513] [1057da8a] DMA< b849a1b0 0

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511527] [1057da8c] DMA  99 10801

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511540] [1057da90] FDA< b849a0d0 0

raspberrypi kernel: [14247.511554] [1057da92] TCM< b849a1b0 0

Comment: What's the question? What's the hardware? What's the OS?

Comment: question is 
I am getting mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt error - how to resolve this? any solution?
OS is linux
hardware is : Raspberry Pi3

Comment: Is your SD card still any good? I usually start getting errors like this on worn-out cards.

Comment: We are not using SD cards. We use a flash memory called emmc.